# QGIS layout issues - font sizes

Tags: qgis, layouts, font

When opening a layout template, after having all fonts neatly set out previously we open it to see all fonts have been enlarged and some template lines often move? No body has opened the workspace in another version and it is just being used by 1 person. Issue occurs across multiple versions.

Comment: Can you provide the layout template in question?

Comment: In what kind of object are the font that change ? (I remember having issue with font size in HTML objet)

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs with HTML text if you use `pt` or `px` units for your font sizes. pt/px units are relativ to the DPI settings of your layout and will change with every DPI setting change. Use `em` units instead.

```html
<span style='font-size:1.5em'>Lorem Ipsum</span>
```